# Python Argparse: Using a single tack as a flag, e.g. `./myscript -5` like Git and CoreUtils

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, argparse

## Using single-tack `-` as a flag in Python Argparse

Many GNU CoreUtils (`head`, `tail`, etc) and Git have a command-line feature that allows one to do e.g.

```sh
$ head -5 ...
$ tail -20 ...
$ git log -5 ...
```

How can I achieve the same effect by using Python's `argparse` module?

### Example Parser

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('-', dest='dash', help='Tell me how many!')
p.add_argument('-n', dest='n', help='This works, but I dislike it!')
p.add_argument('positional', nargs='*')
print(p.parse_intermixed_args())
```

This generates the usagee:

```sh
$ ./example.py --help
usage: example.py [-h] [- DASH] [-n N] [positional [positional ...]]
```

### What works

Using e.g. `-n5`, `-n=5`, and `-n 5` all work as expected.

```sh
$ ./example.py before -n5 after
Namespace(dash=None, n='5', positional=['before', 'after'])

$ ./example.py before -n=5 after
Namespace(dash=None, n='5', positional=['before', 'after'])

$ ./example.py before -n 5 after
Namespace(dash=None, n='5', positional=['before', 'after'])
```

### What Does Not Work As Expected

Here, we can see that `-5` does not work as expected.  Surprisingly, `- 5` does work.

**This first example below is my desired usage, but the result is not what I want.**

```sh
# This does not work, `-5` is considered a positional argument.
# ~~ THIS IS WHAAT I WANT TO HAVE WORK! ~~
$ ./example.py before -5 after
Namespace(dash=None, n=None, positional=['before', '-5', 'after'])

# This works, but is not what I want
$ ./example.py before - 5 after
Namespace(dash='5', n=None, positional=['before', 'after'])
```

Comment: don't use argparse if you want to do something wierd!

Comment: No seriously, I think you are smart enough to either write your own parser of `sys.argv`, or read the `argparse.py` code and figure out what it is doing in this edge case.  `git` etc don't use `argparse`.

Answer (score 2):

As documented in

```
parser.add_argument('-f', '--foo')
```

'-f' is a short option, '--foo' a long.

(First) Long is used for the `dest`, and can be used as '--foo=value'.  Short can be used as '-fvalue' or '-bf5' with a 'store_true' short.

But this usage is the consequence of how the flags are used.  There isn't an up front filter that insists on exact syntax.  '-f=value' should work, and '-foobar' can be used as a long.

Your '-' does not conform to this documented pattern, and is not guaranteed to work properly as either long or short.

```
In [1]: import argparse
In [2]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [3]: a = parser.add_argument('-','-f','--foo')

In [5]: parser.parse_args(['--foo=5'])
Out[5]: Namespace(foo='5')
In [6]: parser.parse_args(['-f5'])
Out[6]: Namespace(foo='5')
In [7]: parser.parse_args(['-5'])
usage: ipython3 [-h] [- FOO]
ipython3: error: unrecognized arguments: -5
     ...
In [8]: parser.parse_args(['-=5'])
Out[8]: Namespace(foo='5')
```

Looks like '-' is handled like a long.  It cannot be used as a short.

Generally `argparse` is an extension of the POSIX getopt practice, but not all Linux utilities use that (especially ones created early in the UNIX development).